# Basic script that sends yourself a mail containing the content randomly picked from a folder of files

Tags: php, javascript, python, html

I know how to code a little, and I think I might know enough to do the following. I've googled a bit, but couldn't find sufficient information to get started. Here's what I'm trying to do:

I write a few notes to the Khan Academy videos I watch. I write them in nvALT, and store them in Dropbox, and I, thanks for the idea by Merlin Mann, I categorise them like this: Econx — title. So, what I'd like to have my little program do:

Send me a mail every morning containing the content of a randomly picked .txt file from my notes folder. Depending on what's easier, it would be the economics notes, so it'd have to be filtered to only pick from the notes that start with "Econx". Or is it easier just to do a seperate folder only with economics notes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Python has many tools in its standard library relevant to your problem.  The [`os`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) module can be used to get a list of files in a directory.  The [`random`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) module has a `choice` function that can select a random element from a list.  The [`poplib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/poplib.html) and [`smptlib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html) modules are relevant to email.  You need to tell us what your programming problem is, and show what you've done so far.

Comment: I haven't actually gotten in to the actual code; I didn't know where to begin...

Answer (score 0):

This problem involves interacting with your operating system and with the internet which makes it a somewhat hefty problem for someone without much programming experience, but if you are willing to dive into it, it will probably be a rather rewarding project for learning.

There are two parts to the task that need to be handled separately. You have to write a program to create and send the email, and then you need to get your operating system to schedule the program to run every morning (which is not something you can do simply in the code of the program.)

Of the languages you listed, Python is the only one you can really use to open a folder on your computer and send the content of one of its files as an email. This documentation will be relevant:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html

You will also probably want to look at Python's os module for listing the files in your directory and opening a file so that you can use its content for body of the email. In particular, the method os.listdir() is used for getting a list of all the files in a folder. Once you have the list, you can use Python's random module to get a random integer, and you can use that number to pick the file out of the directory. The builtin method open() should suffice for opening the file. For the purposes you describe, it makes sense to simply hard code the name of the directory into your code.

The second piece of the problem is scheduling which depends on your operating system.

If you use Mac or Linux, you append a line to your crontab. This post explains how to use crontab.

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/

and this post gives you an example of adding a line to the crontab:

stackoverflow.com/questions/878600/how-to-create-cronjob-using-bash

If you are on Windows, the documentation on this page explains how to schedule a recurring task:

windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/schedule-a-task

(Sorry the last to web addresses aren't links. I don't have enough stack overflow karma to put more than two links in a single post.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. As for "Of the languages you listed, Python is the only one you can really use to open a folder on your computer and send the content of one of its files as an email. This documentation will be relevant:", I guess that it could also just get the content from the .txt from a url on the web, as I store the notes in Dropbox? Would that make it any easier? The progamming involved seems to be way over my head, so I might resolve to pay a developer to do it for me.

Comment: Any help? Or would anyone be interested in coding this little program for me? I'd of course pay whatever'd be reasonable.

Comment: SO is for solving programming problems, not having whole programs written from start to finish.  If you want to hire someone, I suggest you find a website that focuses on that.  A Google search for freelance Python developers will probably turn up multiple good options.